# Is it dangerous to run echo without quotes?

Tags: shell, security, quoting, echo

I've seen couple of similar topics, but they are referring to not quoting variables, which I know could lead to unwanted results.

I saw this code and was wondering would if it be possible to inject something to be run when this line of code executes:

`echo run after_bundle`

Comment: I ran into this when I had: target="\*\*\*LIVE SERVER\*\*\*"; echo target: $target; and the *** expanded into a folder listing...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For the specific case

```
echo run after_bundle
```

quoting is not needed.  No quoting is needed because the argument to `echo` are static strings that contain no variable expansions or command substitutions etc.  They are "just two words" (and as [Stéphane points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/443524/116858), they are additionally constructed out of the [*portable character set*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/basedefs/V1_chap06.html)).

The "danger" comes when you deal with variable data that the shell may expand or interpret. In such cases, care must be taken that the shell does the correct thing and that the result is what's intended.

The following two questions contain relevant information about that:

- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)
- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

---

`echo` is sometimes used to "protect" potentially harmful commands in answers on this site.  For example, I may show how to remove files or move files to a new destination using

```
echo rm "${name##*/}.txt"
```

or

```
echo mv "$name" "/new_dir/$newname"
```

This would output commands on the terminal instead of actually removing or renaming files.  The user could then inspect the commands, decide that they look ok, remove the `echo` and run again.

Your command `echo run after_bundle` may be an instruction to the user, or it may be a "commented out" piece of code that is too dangerous to run without knowing the consequences.

Using `echo` like this, one has to know what the modified command does and one must guarantee that the modified command actually *is* safe (it would potentially *not* be if it contained redirections, and using it on a pipeline doesn't work, etc.)

Comment: Adding quotes isn't *sufficient* to know what a shell would do, however -- just as you can't tell that `echo rm "first file.txt" "second file.txt"` is in any way different from `echo rm "first" "file.txt" "second" "file.txt"`, the output from both being the same. If you want to generate a shell command as output, one *must* use `printf '%q ' rm "first file.txt" "second file.txt"; echo` or something equivalent that re-generates syntactic quoting that evaluates to the `argv` passed.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I _really_ hope nobody copy-paste debugging output and runs it in the shell!

Comment: Generating shell commands and then piping them to `sh` is not exactly an uncommon pattern, and seeing people ask "why does `foo` work when I run it on a command line, but this script that emits that exact string with `echo` in front of the line doesn't?" happens *all the time* here. More to the point, debugging output *isn't helpful* if it hides your bugs -- and if your bugs are related to quoting, then `echo` won't reveal them.

Answer (score 27):

Just an extra note on top of [@Kusalananda's fine answer](/a/443512).

```
echo run after_bundle
```

is fine because none of the characters in those 3 arguments¹ passed to `echo` contain characters that are special to the shell.

And (the extra point I want to make here) there's no system locale where those bytes could translate to characters that are special to the shell.

All those characters are in what [POSIX calls the *portable character set*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap06.html#tag_06_01). Those characters should be present and encoded the same in all character sets on a POSIX system².

So that command line will be interpreted the same regardless of the locale.

Now, if we start using characters outside of that portable character set, it's a good idea to quote them even if they are not special to the shell, because in another locale, the bytes that constitute them may be interpreted as different characters that could become special to the shell. Note that it's whether you're using `echo` or any other command, the problem is not with `echo` but with how the shell parses its code.

For instance in a UTF-8:

```
echo voilà | iconv -f UTF-8 -t //TRANSLIT
```

That `à` is encoded as 0xc3 0xa0. Now, if you have that line of code in a shell script and the shell script is invoked by a user who uses a locale whose charset is not UTF-8, those two bytes could make very different characters.

For instance, in a `fr_FR.ISO8859-15` locale, a typical French locale using the standard single-byte charset that covers the French language (the same used for most western European languages including English), that 0xc3 byte is interpreted as the `Ã` character and 0xa0 as the non-breaking space character.

And on a few systems like NetBSD³, that non-breaking space is considered as a *blank* character (`isblank()` on it returns true, it is matched by `[[:blank:]]`) and shells like `bash` therefore treat it as a token delimiter in their syntax.

That means that instead of running `echo` with `$'voil\xc3\xa0'` as argument, they run it with `$'voil\xc3'` as argument, which means it won't print `voilà` correctly.

It gets a lot worse with Chinese character sets like BIG5, BIG5-HKSCS, GB18030, GBK which have many characters whose encoding contains the same encoding as the `|`, `` ` ``, `\` (to name the worst) (also that ludicrous SJIS, aka Microsoft Kanji, except that it's `¥` instead of `\`, but still treated as `\` by most tools as it's encoded as 0x5c there).

For instance, if in a `zh_CN.gb18030` Chinese locale, you write a script like:

```
echo 詜 reboot
```

That script will output `詜 reboot` in a locale using GB18030 or GBK, `唰 reboot` in a locale using BIG5 or BIG5-HKSCS, but in a C locale using ASCII or a locale using ISO8859-15 or UTF-8, will cause `reboot` to be run because the GB18030 encoding of `詜` is 0xd4 0x7c and 0x7c is the encoding of `|` in ASCII so we end up running:

```
 echo �| reboot
```

(that � representing however the 0xd4 byte is rendered in the locale). Example using the less harmful `uname` instead of `reboot`:

```
$ echo $'echo \u8a5c uname' | iconv -t gb18030 > myscript
$ LC_ALL=zh_CN.gb18030 bash ./myscript | sed -n l
\324| uname$
$ LC_ALL=C bash ./myscript | sed -n l
Linux$
```

(`uname` was run).

So my advise would be to quote all strings that contain characters outside of the portable character set.

However note that since the encoding of `\` and `` ` `` are found in the encoding of some of those characters, it's better not to use `\` or `"..."` or `$'...'` (inside which `` ` `` and/or `\` are still special), but the `'...'` instead to quote characters outside the portable character set.

I'm not aware of any system that has a locale where the charset has any character (other than `'` itself of course) whose encoding contains the encoding of `'`, so those `'...'` should definitely be the safest.

Note that several shells also support a `$'\uXXXX'` notation to express characters based on their Unicode code point. In shells like `zsh` and `bash`, the character is inserted encoded in the locale's charset (though can cause unexpected behaviours if that charset doesn't have that character). That lets you avoid to insert non-ASCII characters in your shell code.

So above:

```
echo 'voilà' | iconv -f UTF-8 -t //TRANSLIT
echo '詜 reboot'
```

Or:

```
echo $'voil\u00e0'
echo $'\u8a5c reboot'
```

(with the caveat the it could break the script when run in locales that don't have those characters).

Or better, since `\` is also special to `echo` (or at least *some* `echo` implementations, at least the Unix compliant ones):

```
printf '%s\n' 'voilà' | iconv -f UTF-8 -t //TRANSLIT
printf '%s\n' '詜 reboot'
```

(note that `\` is also special in the first argument to `printf`, so non-ASCII characters are also better avoided there in case they may contain the encoding of `\`).

Note that you could also do:

```
'echo' 'voilà' | 'iconv' '-f' 'UTF-8' '-t' '//TRANSLIT'
```

(that would be overkill but could give you some peace of mind if you're not sure which characters are in the portable character set)

Also make sure never to use the ancient `` `...` `` form of command substitution (which introduces another level of backslash processing), but use `$(...)` instead.

---

<sup>¹ technically, `echo` is also passed as argument to the `echo` utility (to tell it how it was invoked), it's the `argv[0]` and `argc` is 3, though in most shells nowadays `echo` is builtin, so that `exec()` of a `/bin/echo` file with a list of 3 arguments is simulated by the shell. It's also common to consider the list of arguments as starting with the second one (`argv[1]` to `argv[argc - 1]`) as that's the ones the commands  mainly act upon.</sup>

<sup>² a notable exception to that being the ludicrous `ja_JP.SJIS` locale of FreeBSD systems whose charset has no `\` nor `~` character!</sup>

<sup>³ note that while many systems (FreeBSD, Solaris, not GNU ones though) consider U+00A0 as a `[[:blank:]]` in UTF-8 locales, few do in other locales like those using ISO8859-15, possibly to avoid this kind of issue.</sup>

Comment: In your first paragraph, you tell us "... of the characters in those 3 arguments passed to `echo`...", I only count 2 arguments being passed to the command `echo`, the arguments I can count are `run` and `after_bundle`, care to explain how you counted and got to 3 arguments?

Comment: @ViktorFonic, see edit about the number of arguments (and that the main problem is not with `echo`). See `(exec -a foo /bin/echo --help)` on a GNU system and with the GNU shell for how to pass an arbitrary first argument to the `/bin/echo` utility.

Comment: @Ferrybig See Stephane's edit, footnote 1. Arguments to command in the usual C style are array of arguments, with  argv[0] being executable name itself. Kinda similar to `$0` and positional parameters in shells.

Comment: There are 373 encoding in `iconv` in which `ESC` is converted to `'`. Try (as an example) : `printf '\x1b'|iconv -f utf8 -t IBM-937|xxd`

Comment: There are 173 encoding in which some codepoint (other than ESC) is converted to a `'`. Try `printf '\u2804' | iconv -f utf8 -t BRF | xxd`. There are encodings in which there are a lot of codepoints that become `'`.  Around 8695 codepoints in UCS-4 become `'`. Try `printf '\U627' | iconv -cf utf-8 -t UCS-4`. Several (37) encoding convert the character 0x127 to a `'`. Try `printf '\U127' | iconv -cf utf8 -t UCS2 |xxd`

Comment: @isaac, you won't find a POSIX system where the C locale uses ASCII (with ESC as 0x1b) and that has system locales with such charsets as IBM-937 as the encoding of the portable character set is different between ASCII and them. UCS-4, UTF16 cannot be used as a locale charset, they are not compatible with the POSIX API as they have characters which contain 0 bytes.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Are you saying that a file could not be exchanged between systems? That was the original claim: One system stores a file, some other opens the file misinterpreting some characters.

Comment: @isaac, I'm saying that unless you quote non-ASCII characters with single-quotes, the code can be interpreted differently depending on the locale the user is using on the same system (using ASCII as the C charset. In practice, AFAIK, 99.999% of POSIX systems use ASCII and most of the rest some variant of EBCDIC). (and if you don't do that, that can cause security vulnerabilities, think for instance if it's a script used in a ssh ForcedCommand as in git server deployments, when sshd accepts the LC_* variables and the system has those locales with Chinese charsets)